# Configuring weblogic server console with external server urls, etc

Tags: url, console, weblogic

there are obviously various 'canned' configuration options in oracle's weblogic server console for setting up data sources, jms queues, ldap servers etc, etc.

What i want however is a way to configure other servers, mostly server urls, etc, in the console as well, and allow web applications running on the web server to access those configuration settings at runtime, probably through jndi names. Things like a document management server, a workflow server, etc.

However I'm at a loss for how to configure custom jndi 'data sources' within wls' console. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently weblogic server can't do this by itself...

It looks like this addition will do what i want:

http://code.google.com/p/weblogic-jndi-startup/

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.